# terraform multiple if else statement in one variable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

we have a folder that is used for both prod and nonprod, however, we want to split this into two seperate folders. One issue I'm have is with a multiple if-else statement that looks as follows:

```
elastic_search_host  = "${var.account_name == "prod" ? var.es_friendly_name_part : var.dedicated_es_cluster ? "${var.environment}-${var.es_friendly_name_part}" : "nonprod-${var.es_friendly_name_part}"}.${lookup(var.route53_domains, var.account_name)}"
```

I understand the first part that says, if the account is prod then use 'es_friendly_name_part' otherwise use 'dedicated_es_cluster' but after this I don't understand what is prod and what's not.

I'm assuming this is split into another if-else statement that says, also if prod then use

'"${var.environment}-${var.es_friendly_name_part}"'

otherwise use

"nonprod-${var.es_friendly_name_part}"

but is the .lookup function at the end used regardless of account or is this just non-production?

also if I want to split this so this is just used for production - so no need for if-else how would I do this? would I need to concatenate or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` is equivalent to (pseudo code):

```
if var.account_name == "prod" then
   var.es_friendly_name_part.${lookup(var.route53_domains, var.account_name)}
else 
   
  if var.dedicated_es_cluster != "" then
     ${var.environment}-${var.es_friendly_name_part}.${lookup(var.route53_domains, var.account_name)}
  else
    nonprod-${var.es_friendly_name_part}.${lookup(var.route53_domains, var.account_name)}
  end
 
end
```

> is the .lookup function at the end used regardless of account

Its executed in all cases.

> split this so this is just used for production

If you have only prod, then you have always first condition, which results in:

```
var.es_friendly_name_part.${lookup(var.route53_domains, var.account_name)}
```

Comment: thank you very much Marcin. One question on that. When you put

"if var.dedicated_es_cluster != "" then"

is this saying that if its not production and there is a dedicated es cluster then set the 'elastic_search_host' value equal to:

"${var.environment}-${var.es_friendly_name_part}.${lookup(var.route53_domains, var.account_name)}"?

as I thought whatever came after the colon was to be used this regardless, so how come it has to != ""       thanks very much